# how to make rounded corners button on runtime even if background is already set in xml

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

I understand how to make `Button` has rounded corners using `GradientDrawable`. The question I have now is if I set my background already in xml and retrieve it by

```
int[] attrsArray = new int[] {
        android.R.attr.background
};
TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attrsArray);
Drawable background = ta.getDrawable(0);
ta.recycle();
```

so I have a `Drawable` type of background now. next thing I want to do is call `setBackgroundDrawable()` and pass the drawable background, but I won't be able to set rounded corners with `Drawable` type. I can't just cast it to `GradientDrawable` either. Is there a way to achieve this? this way makes things a lot easier because I'll be able to give `Button` any background and have the rounded corner.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to use a button? Can it be an ImageView? Or an ImageView with an invisible button in front of it?

Comment: @KVISH it can be anything. i'm using button here because its functionality is being used as button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if your use case is same as mine but I had to once do something similar and I had an invisible Button with a RoundedImageView behind it. The RoundedImageView was below:

https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

Using that class you can set the radius of the image.

Comment: not exactly what i was looking for, but it indeed gives me some ideas. thank you!